# How to channel pack texture in python?

Tags: python

I want to channel pack textures i.e. `metallic`, `roughness`, `ao`, and `curvature` into one image in python.

Comment: can you provide more details? i don't understand what you mean by channel pack textures. maybe give an example of textures and the expected output image.

Comment: Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HANAToqXy6A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fetch the pixels from each source image in turn and build the packed pixel array by copying channels over. The `pack_order` variable controls the order in which the channels of the source images get packed into the output.

```
import bpy
import numpy

# Packs an image from channels. The order is described by pack_order.
# Example:
#
#   pack_order = [
#      # Pack G of image1 into B of output
#      (image1, (1, 2)),
#      # Pack R of image2 into R of output
#      # Also pack B of image2 into G of output
#      (image2, (0, 0), (2, 1)),
#   ]

def pack_image_channels(pack_order):
    dst_array = None
    has_alpha = False

    # Build the packed pixel array
    for pack_item in pack_order:
        image = pack_item[0]

        # Initialize arrays on the first iteration
        if dst_array is None:
            w, h = image.size
            src_array = numpy.empty(w * h * 4, dtype=numpy.float32)
            dst_array = numpy.ones(w * h * 4, dtype=numpy.float32)

        assert image.size[:] == (w, h), "Images must be same size"

        # Fetch pixels from the source image and copy channels
        image.pixels.foreach_get(src_array)
        for src_chan, dst_chan in pack_item[1:]:
            if dst_chan == 3:
                has_alpha = True
            dst_array[dst_chan::4] = src_array[src_chan::4]

    # Create image from the packed pixels
    dst_image = bpy.data.images.new("Packed Image", w, h, alpha=has_alpha)
    dst_image.pixels.foreach_set(dst_array)

    # Since the image doesn't exist on disk, we need to pack it into the .blend
    # or it won't exist after the .blend is closed
    dst_image.pack()

    return dst_image
```

---

edit: This, I believe, is how you can use this to implement the functions you requested in your comment.

```
from bpy.types import Image

# Pack four monochrome images into RGBA
def channel_pack(r: Image, g: Image, b: Image, a: Image):
    pack_order = [
        (r, (0, 0)),
        (g, (0, 1)),
        (b, (0, 2)),
        (a, (0, 3)),
    ]
    return pack_image_channels(pack_order)

# Pack the RGB of one an image into the RGB of the output, with a
# monochrome image packed into the alpha.
def alpha_pack(rgb: Image, a: Image):
    pack_order = [
        (rgb, (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)),
        (a, (0, 3)),
    ]
    return pack_image_channels(pack_order)
```

Comment: Can you please convert it into two function i.e. `channel_pack(r: bpy.data.Image, g: bpy.data.Image, b: bpy.data.Image, a: bpy.data.Image)` and `alpha_pack(rgb: bpy.data.Image, a: bpy.data.Image)`

Comment: Will it work on the UDIM image?

Comment: I don't think so. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270293/is-it-possible-to-access-the-pixels-of-individual-udims-in-python-bpy-data-im

Comment: It's creating `RGBA byte` image how can I make it `RGBA float`?

Comment: Same as any image, pass `float_buffer=True` to the [new function](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataImages.html#bpy.types.BlendDataImages.new). You might also want `is_data=True`.